# Error adding icons font ionic 3

Tags: sass, compiler-errors, ionic3

i am noob with Ionic and i am having problems adding a new font of icons in my project.

I am using ionic 3.20.0. I am trying to add this font (http://icofont.com/) and i am use this tutorial for this.
https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/
(I downloaded this project but dont run, i think that the code is old version, but i am not sure)

I made the tutorial step by step but , when i try to run my app i see this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hreX7.jpg)

I read a lot of tutorials and try a lot of ways, but i dont know how import the scss file with the fonts.

Thanks for the help!! ( And sorry for my english...)

Comment: What is the reason for the negative vote? I am new writing in stackoverflow too and will be useful know it, for future post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the error was that i had a extra dot in the name of my file. I check this and all runs ok with the steps indactes in the tutorial and the coments of this.

Thanks.